# Edit Black and White image using HSV color space

Tags: image, hsv, color-space, monochrome

Why Hue and Saturation parameters in HSV colors space not change any thing in black and white (monochrome) images ? except Value (brightness) can change the lightness of the image !

I've tried to change them using Photoshop adj. layer.

Answer (score 1):

A black and white and white image is by definition achromatic thus devoid of hue and coincidentally its saturation is set to zero.

The hue and saturation parameters are usually and respectively performing hue rotation and saturation multiplication. Zero multiplied by something always yields zero, thus nothing happens.